# Unreal Engine 4.27 How can I expose a property to be seen in an Event Graph?

Tags: events, properties, unreal-engine4, mrtk

I am currently working on an application for the Hololens and want to program a button that changes the lighting intensity. I am having trouble finding/referencing this property shown below in my event graph. How can I expose this property to make it editable via a custom event?

[image: The directional light from MRTK. I want to reference the Intensity property.]
The directional light from MRTK. I want to reference the Intensity property.

[image: My button event graph.]

My button event graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you want to access from a blueprint must be `BlueprintReadWrite`.

So in the header of your class you have to declare the class member like this:

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite)
float Intensity = 0.0f;
```

Then in your blueprint you want to drag-off a pin from the return value of `Get Actor Of Class` and you should be able to get and set the value of your variable.